# Finding distance of the race given speeds of two sprinters

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A sprinter who averaged $30$ ft/sec completed a race before another sprinter who averaged $28$ ft/sec. What was the distance of the race if the first sprinter completed the race in $30$ seconds?

This is my solution:

\begin{align} \frac{x}{30} + 30&= \frac{x}{28} \\
14x+12600&=15x\\
\Rightarrow x&=12,600 
\end{align}

Comment: I guess I am getting this wrong, but as I read it it is only asked what distance a sprinter with $30$ ft/sec is running in 30 seconds...?

Comment: Are you sure hat question is correct? If so it’s just asking for the distance covered in 30 seconds at 30ft/second. So... 900ft. There is nothing in the question that requires the need for the second runner.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at your equations, but I can already tell you your solution is not correct, even though the result is, from what I can see, correct).

Let me explain.

---

Maybe the equations are correct, maybe they are not. I don't know. Yet. However, I know that your "solution" is composed only out of three equations. Your solution does not explain what these equations are, and what the variables inside mean. Your solution does not explain how the equations are connected to the task you want to answer. And for that, your solution is already wrong.

---

A much better looking solution would contain **sentences**, because that's how humans communicate. The *story* behind the equations is every bit as important as the equations themselves.

So, your solution would be much better if it started like this:

Let $x$ be the distance of the race (in feet). Then,.... (I recommend you try to write it down like this, and then we can talk whether the formulas are correct or not).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure hat question is correct? If so it’s just asking for the distance covered in 30 seconds at 30ft/second. So... 900ft. There is nothing in the question that requires the need for the second runner.

30ft/sec * 30sec = 900ft